# Scala Function: Issue with variable parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a particular method using Scala within a spark application.
This method has one argument of type:

```
private def tryAgain(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[...],...)
```

My problem is: this argument does not have always the same structure, i.e., it can be:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((java.sql.Date, Int, java.sql.Timestamp, String, String, Int), Int, Int)]
or
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((java.sql.Date, Int, Long, String, String, Int),String)]
or 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((java.sql.Date, String, Int), Int, Int)]
```

So i would like to adapt this method to fit in all these types. How can I do this? I have tried something like this:
`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any]` but it does not work as expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you expect to use the **RDD** if you do not know which type it is?

Answer (score 0):

Generics might solve you issue:

```
  private def tryAgain[T](rdd: RDD[T]) = {...}

  tryAgain(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[((java.sql.Date, String, Int), Int, Int)])
  tryAgain(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[((java.sql.Date, Int, Long, String, String, Int),String)])
  tryAgain(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[((java.sql.Date, Int, java.sql.Timestamp, String, String, Int), Int, Int)])
```

Comment: if my tryAgain method is:

 private def tryAgain[T] (insertResult: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]){
  
    val test = insertResult.filter(x=>x._2==1)
  }

it says: value _2 is not a member of type parameter T

Comment: Quick and dirty solution that comes to mind:

private def tryAgain[K <: Product](rdd: RDD[K]) = {rdd.filter(x => x.productElement(1).asInstanceOf[Int] == 1)}